# How to get this sounddv.py file to run inside the html file using flask?

Tags: python, flask

how do you add sounddv.py to flask and then run in html file?

I want to print this text in popup.html
text = "You must be mumbling you have been checked "+str(check_cnt)+ "times"
this is the py code

Also I want to make that sounddv.py work inside my other html file.

sounddv.py

```
import sounddevice as sd
from numpy import linalg as LA
import numpy as np

duration = 20  

global cnt
global check_cnt
cnt = 0
check_cnt = 0

def print_sound(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata)*10

    a = int(volume_norm)
    global cnt
    global check_cnt

    if a <= 28: 
        cnt = cnt + 1
    
    if cnt == 300: 
        check_cnt += 1
        text = "You must be mumbling you have been checked "+str(check_cnt)+ "times"
        cnt = 0
```

This is the popup html

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>Popup!</head>
    <body>
        <p>
        </p>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the app.py folder

app.py

```
import sounddevice as sd
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
import pymysql
from sounddv.py import print_sound 

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)

@app.route('/audio')
def audio_file():
    with sd.Stream(callback=print_sound):
        duration = 20
        sd.sleep(duration * 1000)
       return render_template("popup.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=5000, debug=True)
```

I'm new to Python :(
I'm opened for any possible comments! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In print_sound return text. Then call it inside your flask audio file function. Also add the variable in return render template like this:

```
return render_template('popup.html',text_var=text)
```

Also in popup.html use jinja ->{{text_var}}

```
    def print_sound(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata)*10
    text=''

    a = int(volume_norm)
    global cnt
    global check_cnt

    if a <= 28: 
        cnt = cnt + 1
    
    if cnt == 300: 
        check_cnt += 1
        text = "You must be mumbling you have been checked "+str(check_cnt)+ "times"
        cnt = 0

return text



 @app.route('/audio')
def audio_file():
    with sd.Stream(callback=print_sound):
        duration = 20
        sd.sleep(duration * 1000)
        text=print_sound(...)
       return render_template("popup.html",text_var=text)
```

Comment: @app.route('/audio')

def audio_file():

    with sd.Stream(callback=print_sound):

        duration = 20

        sd.sleep(duration * 1000)

        return render_template("/companies/popup.html",text_var=text)

I tried but It turns error msg, Can you tell me about this more? Thank you so much. Im new to python:(

Comment: popup.html should be inside the templates folder. Check a simple flask app tutorial to see the base flask app structure. Also, you have to change a little bit your code to pass your string in the text variable.

Comment: umm pop.html is inside the templates folder. the error is with the return render_template.                                                                                                                           w                                                                                                                                                                           it says it says "text" is not defined. how do I push the souddv.py's text into audio_file()?

Answer (score 0):

Your print_sound function does not have any return value. You should add return value in your func. I think.

```
import sounddevice as sd
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
import pymysql
from sounddv.py import print_sound 

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)

@app.route('/audio')
def audio_file():
   ...
   return render_template("popup.html",html_context)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=5000, debug=True)
```

html:

```
<p> {{ html_context }} </p>
```

Comment: it says "html_context" is not defined.  how do you push the souddv.py's text into audio_file()?

Comment: The html_context expression here is the representation of the value you want to send to the html page.

Comment: Add a return value to your print_sound function for example a value named html_context and use it in your view function.